# How should you express a negative binomial distribution (\w gamma function) in an exponential family form?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, exponential-family

How should you express a negative binomial distribution (\w gamma function), i.e.

$$f(y_i, \mu, \phi) = \frac{\Gamma (y+ \phi)}{\Gamma(\phi) \Gamma(y+1)}(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \phi})^y (\frac{\phi}{\mu + \phi})^{\phi}$$

where $\phi$ is assumed to be known,

in an exponential family form?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can. Unless $\phi \in \mathbb{N}$ is known. You can see the problem in the last line.

\begin{align*}
&f(y_i, \mu, \phi) \\
&= \frac{\Gamma (y+ \phi)}{\Gamma(\phi) \Gamma(y+1)}(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \phi})^y (\frac{\phi}{\mu + \phi})^{\phi}\\
&= \exp\left[\log\left(\frac{\Gamma (y+ \phi)}{\Gamma(\phi) \Gamma(y+1)}(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \phi})^y (\frac{\phi}{\mu + \phi})^{\phi} \right) \right] \\
&= \exp\left[\log\left(\frac{\Gamma (y+ \phi)}{\Gamma(\phi) \Gamma(y+1)}\right) + y \log\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \phi}\right) + \phi \log\left(\frac{\phi}{\mu + \phi}\right)  \right] \\
&= \exp\left[\log\Gamma (y+ \phi) - \log\Gamma(\phi) - \log \Gamma(y+1) + y \log\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \phi}\right) + \phi \log\left(\frac{\phi}{\mu + \phi}\right)  \right] \\
&= \exp\left[\log\left[y\cdots (y+\phi-1)\Gamma(y) \right] - \log\Gamma(\phi) - \log \Gamma(y+1) + y \log\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \phi}\right) + \phi \log\left(\frac{\phi}{\mu + \phi}\right)  \right] 
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes I forgot, $\phi$ is assumed to be known.

Comment: ok, well then second to last line is the answer :)